# Azure DevOps YAML: If-else conditions with variables from templates not working

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

**Edit 1:** In the original post I have a typo: inside step #4 I used compile-time expressions which is not correct of course, and in my original pipeline I am using template expressions. Sorry for the confusion - now YAML snippets in this post are identical to my pipeline. And yes, it's still not working.
[Screenshot of execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mRrV.png)

Because of some reason, I have some trouble while using template expressions syntax (If-else statement especially) with variables that are imported from a template. Which broking all logic of my pipeline.
So, I have a quite simple ADO Yaml pipeline:
azure-pipelines.yml

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: applicationType
    type: string
    values:
    - Backend
    - Frontend
    - Others
    default: Backend

trigger: none
resources:
    repositories:
    - repository: Templates
      type: git
      name: Templates

variables:
 - name: applicationType
  value: ${{ parameters.applicationType }}
 - template: vars/vars.yml@Templates
   parameters:
     varAppType:$(applicationType)

stages:
  - stage: Test
    jobs:
      - job: Test
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - bash: echo $(applicationType) #1
        - ${{ if eq(variables.applicationType, 'Backend') }}: #2
          - bash: echo "It is Backend" 
        - ${{ else }}:
          - bash: echo "It is something different"
        - bash: echo $(varAppType) #3
        - ${{ if eq(variables.varAppType, 'Backend') }}: #4
          - bash: echo "It is Backend" 
        - ${{ else }}:
          - bash: echo "It is something different"
```

And here is the snippet of vars/vars.yml which located in Templates repo:

```yaml
parameters:
    - name: varAppType
      default: ''

variables:
- name: varAppType
  value: ${{ parameters.varAppType }}
```

Everything looks fine and straightforward, but here is what I see in logs during the run if I set applicationType as 'Backend':

```
#1 output: Backend
#2 output: It is Backend
#3 output: Backend
#4 output: It is something different
```

Because conditionals only work when used with template syntax I don't even know what else I can try to do.
Its strange why ADO making such a difference between typical vars and imported from template ones, as I thought it should be working well because template syntax get processed at compile time, before runtime starts.
Maybe somebody knows how to fix this and what point I am missing with such a trivial task.
Any help would be appreciated, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Conditional insertion works only with compile-time expressions (${{}}). In your case you use runtime expression ($[]) which is probably the cause your issue.

Comment: That's the crucial point @jdfa; I will vote it up if you post it as an Answer.

Comment: Sorry guys, it is just a typo - in my original pipeline I am using template expressions, but somehow I have made a mistake in the post. So yes, the question is still open and I edited the post. Still thanks for noticing this mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing different types of variables.

```
 - template: vars/vars.yml@Templates
   parameters:
     varAppType:$(applicationType)
```

`$(applicationType)` is macro syntax, which is evaluated at runtime. However, template parameters are resolved at compilation time. Thus,          `varAppType:$(applicationType)` should actually be `varAppType: ${{ variables.applicationType }}` (or more ideally, `${{ parameters.applicationType }}`)  so it can be resolved at compilation time.

However, the mapping of parameters into variables that you're doing is largely unnecessary. You can just reference the parameter directly as `${{ parameters.applicationType }}` throughout. As such, your entire `vars.yml` template is unnecessary.

Another best practices note:

What you're doing here:

`- bash: echo $(applicationType)` is potentially dangerous. Just like SQL injection, you're taking an arbitrary string and injecting it directly into a script. This is called a *script injection vulnerability*.

The better way to handle this is to map your parameter into an environment variable and reference it as an environment variable within your script, as follows:

```
- bash: echo $APP_TYPE
  env:
   APP_TYPE: ${{ parameters.applicationType }}
```

Answer (score 1):

For #4 you are using runtime expression (`$[]`), while for #2 - compile-time expression (`${{}}`). Conditional insertion can work only with compile-time expressions, that's why #4 is not working. More info about expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

To solve your problem you can try to change your pipeline in a way that you would use compile-time expressions or use `condition` field which is present in any step. In second option it would be possible to use runtime expressions

Comment: Oh, my bad, I made mistake in the post - in my original pipeline I am using template expressions (${{ }}) - I don't know why I have put compile-time expressions in post...
Still, If-else statements are not working with compile-time expressions - ADO showing an error about this.